# Flipper Plugin 'UI Debugger' is not supported by the selected application (Android)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flipper

I've been learning React Native app development recently and using Flipper to debug my application. I want to use it to debug the UI, but it's showing a message that says `Plugin 'UI Debugger' is not supported by the selected application 'WmsPda' (Android)`.

The React Native version I'm using is `0.71.4` and the Flipper version is `0.189.0`. I've tried the following:

1. Upgrading the Flipper SDK version. The React Native project comes with version `0.125.0`, so I upgraded it to `0.182.0` (`0.189.0` doesn't seem to be available on Maven Central yet).
2. Installing 'react-native-flipper' to the project using npm.
3. Attempting to initialize the UIDebugger in ReactNativeFlipper using `client.addPlugin(new UIDebuggerFlipperPlugin(UIDContext.Companion.create((Application) context)))`, but it's showing a message that says it can't find the class.

According to the official documentation, the UI Debugger should work on Android and should be available out of the box for React Native versions 0.62 and above. Am I missing something?